# MySql and PHP query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem!

I need to get `player_id` knowing only the player name from one MySQL table with one php query.

My code is this:

```
$user = $_POST['user_search'];

$player_id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$prism_table_players."` WHERE player = '".$user."'");

$player_id_2 = mysql_fetch_array($player_id);

$player_id_3 = $player_id_2['player_id'];
```

I'm already connected to the MySQL database etc... I just need to get the `player_id` when I have only the player name.

If needed the table is structurated like this:

```
player_id  player

3411       John 
4012       Mark
```

I need to get the `player_id` when having just the player

For example I need to get 3411 when I send as html input the player "John"

Resolved guys, here the correct code for extract it:

```
$player_id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$prism_table_players."` WHERE player = '".$user."'");

$player_id_2 = mysql_fetch_row($player_id);

$player_id_3 = $player_id_2['0'];
```

Comment: it seems that your query is okay but you need exact same username as database table contain the name(it is case sensative).

Comment: @AwladLiton: That depends on the column's collation.

Comment: The column "player_id" havent a collation, the column "player" have as collation "utf8_general_ci"

Comment: Indeed.  The `_ci` indicates that it is case insensitive: so @AwladLiton's point is incorrect.

Comment: Have you verified that `$user` does indeed contain `'John'` as expected?  Have you verified that `$prism_table_players` does indeed contain the name of your table?

Comment: It might be helpful to future users if you could explain what the problem was and how you resolved it: feel free to post as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're application isn't safe. User input is directly put into query and this allows your user to destroy your database. Secondly, you're using `mysql_*` functions - it is not recommended, use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead. To get player_id from your array, you have to use:

```
$user = $_POST['user_search'];

$player_id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$prism_table_players."` WHERE player = '".$user."'");

$player_id_2 = mysql_fetch_row($player_id);

$player_id_3 = $player_id_2[0];
```

It would be better if you would use mysqli prepared statements.

Comment: Whilst I agree with the opening paragraph, why do you think that using `mysql_fetch_row()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()` will make any difference?

Comment: I'm not sure if `mysql_fetch_array()` will return array such as `$result[0]['column']` or `$result['column']` when there's only one row.

Comment: I've read but still wasn't sure so I thought as long as player name is unique he won't need more than one row so it would be safer for me to use `mysql_fetch_row()` in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You really **should NOT use the mysql_* functions** - they are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). Use either MySQLi or PDO connection; I personally prefer PDO so I'll write this as PDO:

```
//just to demonstrate the connection part:
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
//the important stuff
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("Select player_id from {$prism_table_players}
    WHERE player = :player");
$stmt->execute(array("player" => $_POST['user_search']));
$entry = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$player_id = $entry['player_id'];
```

Comment: What is it about merely switching to PDO that you think would fix the OP's problem?

Comment: Well it will make it secure and given proper indicing & collation that query will be efficient and return the player_id for the given name

Comment: I see.  But what is it about the OP's original query that you believe was causing it not to work?

Comment: as no note of specific problems I can't say any more than that but that is reasonably secure so a vast improvement to my mind

Answer (score -2):

```
// try to execute below echo in phpmyadmin or mysql console
echo $query = "SELECT * FROM `".$prism_table_players."` WHERE player = '".$user."'"

$player_id = mysql_query($query);
```

You can use trim() for

```
$user = trim($_POST['user_search']);
```

or

```
// try to execute below echo in phpmyadmin or mysql console
    echo $query = "SELECT * FROM `".$prism_table_players."` WHERE player LIKE '".$user."'"

    $player_id = mysql_query($query);
```